# Render SVG HAML template with Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, sass, asset-pipeline, haml

I have an SVG I created using HAML to keep the syntax clean.  I can use the image as a background image in CSS using a Rails route just fine, but I'd really like to precompile the svg.haml into an svg and serve it statically.

Is there a way to add a templated SVG to the asset pipeline and reference it from SCSS in such a way that the SVG can be precompiled as a static asset with a digest like the rest of my assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's an example SVG (seal.svg.haml) I have in app/assets/images:

```
points = 60; interval = 360.0 / points

%svg{xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'xmlns:xlink' => 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xmlns:svg' => 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', viewBox: '0 0 200 200'}
  %defs
    %polygon#point{points: '100,0 104,8 96,8'}

  %g{fill: '#333'}
    %circle{cx: 100, cy: 100, r: 88, stroke: '#333', 'stroke-width' => 2, fill: 'transparent'}

    - points.times do |point|
      %use{'xlink:href' => '#point', 'transform' => "rotate(#{interval * point} 100 100)"}
```

Then, I registered the haml engine for the assets pipeline with config/initializers/haml_assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.assets.register_engine '.haml', Tilt::HamlTemplate
```

Then, this works fine:

```
.seal {
  background: transparent url(asset_path('seal.svg')) no-repeat center top;
}
```